# How to search not by one, but load a result list as in vs2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

How to search not by one, but load a result list as in vs2008? For me working only "Find Next" kind of search. Although "Find Results" window is appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2008, make sure your solution is open with at least one file.  Enter Ctrl+F and the Find Replace screen pops up.  Quick Find is selected by default, click the drop down arrow and select Find in Files.  Click Find Files and "Boom goes the dynamite", now you have a list of findings. If you click on one it brings you to the file location.